# For Realm Swift, could I use DispatchQueue with autorelease frequency of .workItem instead of autoreleasepool?

Tags: swift, multithreading, realm

From the doc we should be using:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
    autoreleasepool {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
        try! realm.write {
            theDog!.age = 3
        }
    }
}
```

However, that usage seems exactly how the following does:

```
DispatchQueue(label: "background", autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem).async {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let theDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("age == 1").first
    try! realm.write {
        theDog!.age = 3
    }
}
```

Could someone confirm the second approach works as expected?

Comment: Any chance you were able to confirm this yet? Would be nice to remove these blocks and use .workItem

Comment: I'm still curious about this